# SELECT value count split comma in a field

Tags: php, mysql, select, split

if I have a list of fields in the database is spliced ​​with a comma , for example

```
    Field1    Field2
Row1 name1     1,3,5
Row2 name2     1,5,2
Row3 name3     3,6,2
.
.
.
RowN NameN     .....
```

how do I determine the 3 numbers who do more in php with mysql?
Thanks

Comment: can you somehow clarify what you're asking for?

Comment: You should not have multiple values in a database table field (making a compound value). Better practise is to create a second table with the name of the first table row as a foreign key and then run a query that says to get all values from the second table that have the name from the first table that you want to reference. This is part of normalisation and ensures that there is only one value in each field of the db.

Answer (score -1):

```
$array = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Field2 FROM table");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $merge = explode(',', $row['Field2']);
    $array = array_merge($array, $merge);
}
$count = array_count_values($array);
rsort($count);
$final = array_slice($count, 0, 3);
print_r($final);
```

Comment: Can you explain your code and how this answers the question?  Code only answer are considered low quality.

Comment: Added 2 more lines. I thought it was enough